# Windows iOS Emulator that uses Apple App Store

Tags: windows, ios

Does any emulator emulates an iPhone completely?

That is, let's you use any app, iTunes, download from Apple App store, use any app as a normal use, take screenshots and so on?

The options I found seem to let me test only apps developed by myself.

Answer (score 1):

No, no such emulator exists (yet). It is unlikely that such an emulator will be available for public use within a short timeframe.

Comment: Why the downvote when the answer is correct?

Comment: Well, the first sentence is true, but the second sentence is pure speculation. Regardless, I’ll offset the downvote.